# Erro na lógica controle de TV - Java

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

Sou iniciante em java e estou com dificuldade em fazer o botão `btnVolumeUp` aumentar o contador.

Primeiro tenho esta classe Televisor no qual criei os métodos.

```
public class Televisor {
int canal = 0; 
int volume = 0;
boolean ligar = false;

public int diminuiVolume(){ //Diminui o volume da TV      
    //Se o volume estiver no 0 Exibe msg e não diminui mais
    if (volume == 0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O volume está no minimo");
    }
    else{
        volume--;
    }
    return this.volume;
}

public int aumentaVolume(){ //Aumenta o volume da TV       
    //Se o volume estiver no 10 Exibe msg e não aumenta mais
    if (volume == 10){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O volume está no máximo");
    }
    else{
        volume++;
    }    
    return this.volume;
}
```

E então tenho um jFrame com os botões de volume e um Label para exibir o volume atual. Porém o botão só funciona na primeira vez. Exemplo: Ao clicar a primeira vez no `btnVolumeUp` o contador vai de 0 para 1, mas depois disso mais nada acontece.

```
 private void btnVolumeUpActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
          Televisor controle = new Televisor();          
          String exibeVolume;          
          exibeVolume = String.valueOf(controle.aumentaVolume());//Converte valor Int para String          
          lblVolume.setText(exibeVolume);//Altera o volume exibido              
    }                                           

    private void btnVolumeDownActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        Televisor controle = new Televisor();          
          String exibeVolume;          
          //controle.aumentaVolume();          
          exibeVolume = String.valueOf(controle.diminuiVolume());//Converte valor Int para String
          lblVolume.setText(exibeVolume);//Altera o volume exibido
    }
```

Essa minha lógica está errada ?

Comment: Está porque cada vez que o método `btnVolumeUpActionPerformed` é chamado este está a criar uma nova instância de *Televisor*, inicializando o valor de `volume`. O objecto *Televisor* deve ser instanciado fora desse método.

Comment: Então neste caso eu teria que instanciar a classe televisor fora dos botões ?

Comment: Estava a editar o meu comentário para referir isso mesmo.

Comment: Acabei de testar aqui e funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolvido com ajuda do @ramaral.

Agora estou instanciando `Televisor controle = new Televisor();` fora dos botões, assim não é inicializado toda vez em que clico nos botões, evitando voltar o valor de volume para 0.

Desta forma:

```
 Televisor controle = new Televisor();
 private void btnVolumeUpActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
          String exibeVolume;          
          exibeVolume = String.valueOf(controle.aumentaVolume());//Converte valor Int para String          
          lblVolume.setText(exibeVolume);//Altera o volume exibido              
    }                                           

    private void btnVolumeDownActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {            
          String exibeVolume;          
          //controle.aumentaVolume();          
          exibeVolume = String.valueOf(controle.diminuiVolume());//Converte valor Int para String
          lblVolume.setText(exibeVolume);//Altera o volume exibido
    }
```

Comment: Poderia marcar sua resposta como correta? :)

Comment: Marcado! No dia eu tentei mas só pode dois dias após e então esqueci ^^